# Is わきみち wakimichi 【脇道 · わき道】 common?

Tags: words, usage

I would like to know if わきみち *wakimichi* 【脇道 · わき道】 is common. It's my understanding that it means "side street" or "alley".

Comment: If an answer solved your problem please click the checkmark below the number of votes on the answer which helped you. I tell you that because I noticed you have still accepted 0 answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Balanced Corpus of Contemporary Written Japanese (BCCWJ, 少納言, via http://nlb.ninjal.ac.jp), 脇道 has 129 entries

```
脇道　  103 results
わき道   25 results
傍道　    1 result
```

So, 脇道 is the most common spelling. A few words of roughly the same frequency you might know are 小皿 (129), ガールフレンド (129), かき氷 (129), レーズン (130), 嫁入り (130). So, for something meaning "side street" I would say that it's common enough to be worth remembering.

Comment: Thank you.   It helps when I know a word is worth remembering.   I don't want to waste time on words that are not as useful or not common.   Appreciate the help